# All years and months between 2 dates SQL

Tags: sql

I have a little question I have a table called project that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------
 ProjectId  | StartDate   | EndDate   |
---------------------------------------
     1      | 01/01/2015  | 31/12/2017|
```

Is it posible to get all months and years between those dates like this:

```
--------------------
| Month   |   Year  |
--------------------
    1     |   2015  |
    2     |   2015  |
    3     |   2015  |
    4     |   2015  |
    5     |   2015  |
    6     |   2015  |
    7     |   2015  |
    8     |   2015  |
    9     |   2015  |
    10    |   2015  |
    11    |   2015  |
    12    |   2015  |
    1     |   2016  |
    2     |   2016  |
    3     |   2016  |
    4     |   2016  |
    .     |     .   |
    .     |     .   |
    .     |     .   |
    12    |   2017  |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: StartDate and EndDate data type(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using PostgreSQL functions `generate_series` and `extract`:

```
SELECT extract(month FROM date) AS month, extract(year FROM date) AS year
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, '2017-12-31'::date, '1 month'::interval) AS date
) AS date_range
```

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

You'd need to modify this to use the dates from your table:

```
SELECT extract(month FROM range) AS month, extract(year FROM range) AS year
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(StartDate, EndDate, '1 month'::interval) AS range
    FROM project
    WHERE ProjectId = 1
) AS date_range
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database is sql server, you can run the following code to get the result.

```
DECLARE @DateStart DATETIME = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = ' 2017-12-31';
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@DateStart) - 1), @DateStart) AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [Date])
    FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@DateEnd) - 1), @DateEnd)
)
SELECT
MONTH([Date]) AS [Month],
YEAR([Date]) AS [Year]
FROM Dates;
```

Hope it will help. If you need more help, you can look at the following link
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/12/22/sql-server-list-the-name-of-the-months-between-date-ranges-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server, query for your date type

```
    ;with datecte (date)
AS
 (
    SELECT Convert(date,'01/01/2015',105)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from datecte
    where DATEADD(month,1,date)<= (Select Convert(date,'31/12/2017',105))
)
select month(date),YEAR(date) from datecte
```